# php mysql group_concat

Tags: php, mysql

sample table:

```
name           subject   grade    status    
-----------------------------------------  
john peter      engl     NULL       X  
john peter      math     85         A  
john peter      philo    NULL       X  
mark lewis      engl     90         A  
mark lewis      math     NULL       X
```

sample query:

```
<?php  
$query="SELECT name, grade, status, group_concat(subject SEPARATOR '-') as subj   
FROM grades GROUP BY name ORDER BY name";  
$result = $mysqli->query($query);  
<?php } ?>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>Math</td>
    <td>English</td>
    <td>Philosopy</td>  
</tr>  

<?php while($row = $result->fetch_array()){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
<td><?php if (strpos($row['subj'],'math')!== false) {echo 'I';}?></td>
<td><?php if (strpos($row['subj'],'engl')!== false) {echo 'I';}?></td>
<td><?php if (strpos($row['subj'],'philo')!== false) {echo 'I';}?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

sample output:

```
name          Math  English  Philosopy
john peter     I      I         I
mark lewis     I      I
```

now comes what i want to achieve:
i would like to display the status if its value is X, 
like this: or is there a much much better way to do this?
thanks you guys..

```
name          Math  English  Philosopy
john peter     I      X         I
mark lewis     X      I
```

Comment: Why not test/echo `$row['status']` and either print the 'X' or an 'I'?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT  name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'Math' THEN IF(status = 'X', 'X', 'I') END) MATH,
        MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'Engl' THEN IF(status = 'X', 'X', 'I') END) ENGLISH,
        MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'Philo' THEN IF(status = 'X', 'X', 'I') END) Philiosophy
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ebfd/2)

Comment: *follow-up question: how come `mark lewis` has a status of `x` in `match`?*